# Scraping the web data from different pages using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I know how one can extract a tabular data from website using R. However I am not sure how to scrape the data from a website with different pages in it. For e.g. https://www.msn.com/en-in/money/photos/50-richest-people-on-the-planet-in-2016/ss-AAhIs7m?ocid=spartandhp#image=1 . This particular website contains 50 richest people in this world with their age and net worth with other values. I want to extract their age and net worth using R. How can I do that?

Any help appreciated.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I tried XML package's readHTMLTable and readHTMLList ; its not working

Comment: It doesnt actually have 50 page. The image slide is just hiding and showing certain `div` elements. If you look at the page elements within chromes developer tools, or browser you use, you will see what I mean. I can't help too much scraping in R as I do it with Python and `BeautifulSoup` but it should be fairly easy to just parse through the body and use the `id` and `class` of the elements you want to pull out the info you need.

Comment: it is throwing an error : 
VM122:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'class="caption"' is not a valid selector.(…)

Comment: @Artiga sorry for that, i forgot the `[]`. Really sorry for that. I copied the wrong thing across. `document.querySelectorAll('[class="expand"]')`, The strange thing is that if you were to load the page and run that in the console straight away it seems to not find any element until you do some interaction with the page, even just scrolling will load the elements

Comment: @Artiga looking at the `html` it seems like there is some `AJAX` going on loading the data so if you were to read the `html` in with `rvest` for example the elements` wont be pulled through.

Comment: Post your code. Show your work

Comment: @Artiga Do you need the solution yet? If I publish it and it's okay, will you approve it?

Comment: @HenryNavarro, Sure I will.